# Public network Wi-Fi connection problems

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, packet-loss

My friend and I have free public Wi-Fi at college.  Her Wi-Fi used to work fine, and still does in the other buildings.  However, for a long time now her Wi-Fi (which has excellent connection) won't connect to the Internet, while my Wi-Fi (sitting right beside her) will connect to the Internet. (Keep in mind in both instances there was a connection to the network.)

We both have Windows 7 so I went through both of our computers’ network connection options and firewall settings, and everything seemed to be the same. She uses a different adapter driver (Atheros AR5B97 Wireless Network Adapter) while I use (Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC), but I’m pretty sure this is unrelated information and has nothing to do with the problem she is experiencing. She says that her Wi-Fi connects fine in the other buildings; however, it may not be the same network. She also connects fine to other public networks in town.

While I was trying to diagnose the problem on her computer, it randomly switched and said that it had Internet access. Well, we really didn’t. As the packets received were so low, no web pages would pull up. At times she had over 500,000 packets sent and only 1,000 packets received. However, mine would have more packets received than sent, and my Internet was working great.

Regarding the public network, the IP Default Gateway for both computers were the same, as well as the DHCP Server. The DNS Servers were different, so maybe they’re supposed to be unique for each computer.

Interestingly enough her connection speed to the network was double mine, hers ranging above 140mbps while mine almost half that speed.

Comment: I went to her system and security > action center, and it says her windows defender is out of date and need for virus protection.  Would any of these be preventing her internet connection?

Comment: To indicate that your question has been resolved, you can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it as the best answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the "check" symbol below the voting controls. You do not need to edit the title of your question to indicate that it is resolved. See also: [Is it OK to add \[Solved\] to the title of a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The DNS Servers were different

What you are describing could easily be a DNS problem.

See this SU blog entry for more info: [Windows 7 Network Awareness: How Windows knows it has an internet connection](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/)

Pertinent blurb:

> How does it work?
>
> Windows does indeed check a Microsoft site for connectivity, using the
>   Network Connectivity Status Indicator site. There are a few variations
>   of the connection checking process:
>
> 1. NCSI performs a DNS lookup on www.msftncsi.com, then requests http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt. This file is a plain-text file and
>      contains only the text Microsoft NCSI.
> 2. NCSI sends a DNS lookup request for dns.msftncsi.com. This DNS address should resolve to 131.107.255.255. If the address does not
>      match, then it is assumed that the internet connection is not
>      functioning correctly.

Set hers to match yours, or use one of the [many publically available DNS services](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm) (ie: Google's 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4).

Screenshot example:

[image]

Comment: I really feel this information is vague to my knowledge of computers. Are you telling me I need to find and install windows "Network Connectivity Status Indicator" on her computer? Or should I simply try to find a way to manually set her DNS services to match mine.  Would that cause any problems if I did change her DNS services?

Comment: No I'm attempting to point out how a faulty DNS server (setting) can cause Windows to report that it has no Internet connection.  "Or should I simply try to find a way to manually set her DNS services to match mine" that's what I'm saying.  Just manually set her network settings to use the same DNS server that yours is set to use (or a well known public one), and that will probably fix it up, (or at least help us determine if that's the problem).

Comment: If you change what DNS server she is using, then it MIGHT cause problems if she's on a domain, but based on what you say ("Public Wifi") it doesn't sound like she is, so it shouldn't' create any problems.  If it does, switch it back -- it's not a permanent, can-never-be-changed-again setting. :)

Comment: PS: If you read the SU blog I linked and click on the "Network Connectivity Status Indicator" link it will tell you all about it. The first sentence: "Windows ... *includes a feature called Network Connectivity Status Indicator* (NCSI)" ;)

Comment: It's fixed. I switched the options from "use the following DNS server" to "obtain DNS server address automatically".  I'm not sure how or why the DNS server was preset, but right after I set it to automatically obtain a DNS address it started working. Thanks! :]

Comment: Good to hear, congrats! :)

Answer (score 0):

You say this:

> She uses a different adapter driver (Atheros AR5B97 Wireless Network
>   Adapter) while I use (Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E
>   NIC), but I’m pretty sure this is unrelated information and has
>   nothing to do with the problem she is experiencing.

What makes you think that’s the case? Here are the specs on each adapter; emphasis in bold is mine:

[**Atheros AR5B97 Wireless Network Adapter**](http://www.innovelec.co.uk/uploads/docs/qcadata/AR9287.pdf)

- Single-chip, 802.11n-compliant wireless LAN client solution with integrated MAC, baseband and 2.4 GHz radios
- Based on fourth-generation 802.11n compliant technology
- **Support for 2x2 MIMO**
- Conserves power with 1x1 downshift using Dynamic MIMO Power Save
- Enables PHY rate of up to 300 Mbps on downlink
- Compliant with IEEE 802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11d, 802.11e,
  802.11i, and 802.11n
- Lead-free RoHS compliant

[**Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC**](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=273)

- 48-pin QFN
- CMOS MAC, Baseband PHY, and RF in a single chip for IEEE 802.11b/g/n compatible WLAN
- **Complete 802.11n solution for 2.4GHz band**
- 72.2Mbps receive PHY rate and 72.2Mbps transmit PHY rate using 20MHz bandwidth
- 150Mbps receive PHY rate and 150Mbps transmit PHY rate using 40MHz bandwidth
- Compatible with 802.11n specification
- Backward compatible with 802.11b/g devices while operating in 802.11n mode

Now, I am not a 100% expert on 802.11n networking, but I believe that 802.11n in MIMO (on the Atheros AR5B97) would be operating on the 5 Ghz radio spectrum. Whereas non-MIMO 802.11n would operate at 2.4 Ghz.

The key being, that I believe your friend using the Atheros AR5B97 is connecting at 802.11n on 5 Ghz while you are connecting with your Realtek RTL8188CE on 2.4 Ghz. The key to me assuming it is this:

> While I was trying to diagnose the problem on her computer, it
>   randomly switched and said that it had Internet access. Well, we
>   really didn’t. As the packets received were so low, no web pages would
>   pull up. At times she had over 500,000 packets sent and only 1,000
>   packets received. However, mine would have more packets received than
>   sent, and my Internet was working great.

In my experience, when 802.11n screws up is when it is in “mixed mode” where 802.11b/g is allowed from the router as well as 802.11n. I have never been happy when my home Wi-Fi—an Airport Express—was in that mode. But when I had it locked in 802.11n purely, all was great.

Now of course, if you are using public Wi-Fi networks there is no way you can just tell someone to change their public Wi-Fi routers to suit your needs, right?  Well what I would recommend then is asking your friend who is using the Atheros AR5B97 to see if they can adjust their Wi-Fi driver settings to only connect at a specific 802.11n speed. Chances are the driver is set to connect at whatever “fastest” connection it can get, but perhaps forcing the driver to connect at 802.11n on 2.4Ghz will clear things up.

As for why she has no issues on other public networks? Maybe just better maintained and managed routers with more knowledgeable networking staff? Who knows. But I do know the whole world of 802.11n can be a headache. And I am pretty sure the issue you are describing is connected to the world of non-standard 802.11n mixups.

Comment: "forcing the driver to connect at 802.11n on 2.4Ghz will clear things up."

I don't know how to do this.  I went to Atheros AR5B97 Wireless Network Adapter Properties and found little modifiable options. However under the Advanced tab I found these properties which were changeable.

802.11 Bluetooth High Speed - (Enable)/Disable
802.11b Preamble - (Long and Short)/Long Only
AdHoc 11n - (Disable)/Enable
Network Address - (Not Present)/Value: _____
Receive Buffers - Value: 256 *adjustable*
Scan Valid Interval - Value: 60 *adjustable*
Transmit Buffers - Value: 512 *adjustable*

End of options.

Comment: I also looked up the driver and it can be updated. Updating it wouldn't hurt anything, correct? Should I advise her to update it when she has internet at home?